# docker compose psql: error: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I faced a problem when I try to use psql command with my docker-compose file on my local Ubuntu machine:
`psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

I tried to use others solution like removing docker image, volume. `psql -U postgres` doesn't work for me either.

I try to use first `docker-compose up`, then `docker exec -it database bash`

There's my docker-compose file

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Maybe this string tells something?
`postgres | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization`

OUTPUT:

````
Attaching to postgres
postgres | 
postgres | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres | 
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:29:10.426 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424) 10.3.1 20210424, 64-bit
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:29:10.426 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:29:10.426 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:29:10.429 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:29:10.433 UTC [12] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-02 17:22:17 UTC
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:29:10.438 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:37:53.452 UTC [33] FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:37:56.958 UTC [35] FATAL:  role "user" does not exist
postgres | 2021-08-02 17:41:54.294 UTC [45] FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist```
````

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you've set `POSTGRES_USER` to `root`, so you're going to have a `root` user instead of `postgres` user.

Second, if a database already exists, it doesn't matter what you set for `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` -- postgres will use whatever is in the database.

So you can either:

1. Delete the database (`rm -rf data/db`) and start over, or
2. [Edit your `pg_hba.conf` so that you don't need a password](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-reset-password/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this would have fixed things? making sure the user matches the username makes sense, but with that change, and destroying/re-up-ing the container, you would still get this error because the image does not appear to create the `postgres` user role at any point. Also note that according to https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres, the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` env var set to `trust` should prevent any need for messing with the .conf file.

Comment: The image creates (when initializing a new database) whatever user is defined in `POSTGRES_USER` (e.g. `postgres` in this question).

Comment: I have a docker-compose very similar to the one in the OP, and it very much does not, even after blasting it away and rebuilding it =(

Comment: I refer you to [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), which says about `POSTGRES_USER`: "This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of postgres will be used." If it doesn't behave that way for you, feel free to open a new question and we can figure out what's going on with your environment.

Comment: fair enough, will do.

Comment: with: rm -rf data/db .... worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! It took me two hours to figure out that I should find `rm -rf`

Answer (score 18):

If you're using 'docker volumes', you are likely using the same volume in another project (at least I was), and the database already exists.

Renaming the volume fixed the issue for me:

```
volumes:
  volume_name:                                 # <- Rename "volume_name"
    name: volume_name                          # <- Rename "volume_name"

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=pguser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - volume_name:/var/lib/postgresql/data    # <- Rename "volume_name"
```

Answer (score -2):

`docker-compose exec web rake db:migrate db:create` - I have above error: role "..." does not exist.
When I try:
`docker-compose exec web rake db:drop`
`docker-compose exec web rake db:setup`
it's working.